# Can't connect ArcGIS Pro to GeoNode/GeoServer WFS

Tags: arcgis-pro, wms, wfs, geonode

I'm having problems connecting ArcGIS Pro to GeoNode WFS/WMS server using basic authentication. I can connect fine with QGIS. In QGIS I just setup the connection to https://gis.mygeonode.com/gs/wfs and then use basic username and password authentication and it works absolutely fine.

In ArcGIS I go through the same process and it does connect to the server but it does not show any layers available.

I have looked at the Apache logs and there's a clear difference in the requests - the QGIS request generates an access token and then uses that token in following requests to get the layers and data.

For ArcGIS there is no access token generated, but if I customise the request and add the access token that QGIS generated, it works fine.

So it seems like ArcGIS isn't authenticating properly. Has anyone else come across this and how did you fix it?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please also [Edit] the Question to specify the release to Pro in use.

Comment: "In ArcGIS I go through the same process...".  Please include this process in fine detail (edit your original question to include this additional information).

Answer (score 0):

Check this setting in Geoserver, it did the trick for me.

- Select the MIXED option from the Catalog Mode section:

https://docs.geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/esri/arcgis.html